# SQL Server calendar year partition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using SQL Server Management Studio. I want to partition based on `proj_id` and `Years(date)` so that it produces a cumulative sum based off these categories. I did try the following however the `YEAR(date)` I have input in this code doesn't appear to do what i thought it would do.

I'm fairly new to SQL too...

I want the same years for for projectid to consolidate together.

So if I have this input:

```
Dates            Production   projectid      
---------------------------------------
2026-09-05       10           4                
2026-10-05       20           4                
2026-11-05       20           4                 
2027-09-05       15           5                 
2028-09-05       15           6
```

I expect to get this output:

```
Dates            Production   projectid      cumulativesum
-----------------------------------------------------------
2026-09-05       10           4                    10             
2026-10-05       20           4                    30
2026-11-05       20           4                    50
2027-09-05       15           5                    15 
2028-09-05       15           6                    15
```

I have got some code where I want it, however I have not incorporated the partitioning by year... I did try

```
SELECT
    Prod.Electro.*, Ap.Proj.id, Ap.Proj.name,
    SUM(production) OVER (PARTITION BY proj_id, YEAR(date) ORDER BY date, proj_id) AS Cumulative_sum
FROM 
    Prod.Electro
LEFT JOIN 
    Ap.Proj ON Prod.Electro.project_id = Ap.Proj.id
```

Comment: What do you mean by didnt work? Please edit your question to include sample input and expected output

Comment: Sounds like the function you're looking for is DATEPART (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datepart-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16).

Comment: What did you "think it would do"?  Please edit your question to include sample input and exact expected output, based on that specific input.

Comment: Use simple aggregation (SUM and GROUP BY) and not the SUM window function.  The window function use does not generate grouped detail in the result. If you want a running sum over the grouped sum, you can use both.

Comment: What is the issue with the query that you have posted ? Is it working ?

Comment: In your query : `PARTITION BY proj_id` . The column `proj_id` is from which table ? You should alias your table and then prefix all columns that you reference with the alias

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

[The test case](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=4e1c56ecbb82ec45ce58acbc67b1b6e4)

Your SQL is "almost" in the proper form.  Notice the ORDER BY in the OVER clause. The SUM will be done within each partition already.  So there was no need to add proj_id to that ORDER BY clause.

You also didn't provide enough detail to comment on the JOIN logic.  Here's the data and result as you described without the joined tables, which were not part of the given data.

```
SELECT Dates, Production, projectid
     , SUM(Production) OVER (PARTITION BY projectid, YEAR(Dates) ORDER BY Dates) AS sum
  FROM tbl
 ORDER BY projectid, Dates
;
```

The test case and result:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl (Dates date, Production int, projectid int);

INSERT INTO tbl VALUES
    ('2026-09-05', 10, 4)
  , ('2026-10-05', 20, 4)
  , ('2026-11-05', 20, 4)
  , ('2027-09-05', 15, 5)
  , ('2028-09-05', 15, 6)
;
```

| Dates | Production | projectid | sum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2026-09-05 | 10 | 4 | 10 |
| 2026-10-05 | 20 | 4 | 30 |
| 2026-11-05 | 20 | 4 | 50 |
| 2027-09-05 | 15 | 5 | 15 |
| 2028-09-05 | 15 | 6 | 15 |